# Run schedule after saving custom setting's data. Is it possible?

Tags: customsetting

I am having difficulties in custom settings. Is it possible that I can run a schedule after saving the client's credentials? I am using custom settings and the type is hierarchy. Am i gonna create visualforce page or not?

Comment: by any chance is [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/58849/jan) a duplicate account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Settings don't support triggers. You can perform both synchronous and asynchronous operations from whatever user interface you provide for editing these settings, such as a Visualforce page or Lightning component, after you perform a DML `update` or `insert` on the Custom Setting record.

You don't have options for performing synchronous actions fired by an administrator directly changing Custom Settings values in Setup. While you could run a Scheduled Apex job to poll for updates, this is almost certainly not a good design for whatever you're aiming at.

Comment: I'm sorry I am new in Salesforce and still on the process of learning it. Could you provide me further discussions or ways about running schedule on insert of values for custom settings fields.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much more to say, @jan, unless you can be more specific. You need to write a user interface to allow the user to update those Custom Settings if you want to run code after they're changed. Otherwise, you're stuck with the system UI, where you don't have that option.